# Hover on ul child element effect ul after style

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Am I able to do this using **css** only, else jQuery?

Want to target `ul:after` if i hover over the first `li` within an `ul`.

```css
ul.secondary:after {
    border-color: #f3f4f1 transparent;
    border-width: 0 8px 8px;
    right: 11px;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    border-style: solid;
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
} 

/*this is not working*/
ul.secondary li:first-child a:hover + ul.primary ul.secondary::after {
      border-color: #9caa9c transparent; 
}


ul.secondary li:first-child a:hover {
      color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul class="primary">
  <li>
      <ul class="secondary">
          <li><a href="">hover me makes ":after" change border color</a></li>
          <li><a href="">text</a></li>
          <li><a href="">text</a></li>
          <li><a href="">text</a></li>
          <li><a href="">text</a></li>
      </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: That is an interresting proposition!

Comment: @ylama it's not possible to target a parent element when hovering a child with pure css

Comment: @anderssonola oky cool thanks then will take your word ,thats sad news tho

Comment: jquery sulotion then maybe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't write jquery for `pseudo elements` either. But you can do something like this. I added `content:"hi"` instead of `content:""` to show you how it work in `:after` that you have.

```js
$('.secondary>li:first-child>a').mouseover(function(){
  $('.secondary').addClass('hover');
  //You can write whatever you want in here
});
$('.secondary>li:first-child>a').mouseout(function(){
  $('.secondary').removeClass('hover');
  //You can write whatever you want in here
});
```

```css
ul.secondary:after {
  content:"";
  border-color: #f3f4f1 transparent;
  border-width: 0 8px 8px;
  right: 11px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  position: absolute;
}
ul.secondary li:first-child a:hover {
  color: red;
}
ul.secondary.hover:after {
    border-color: red transparent;
}
ul.secondary.hover>li{
   color:black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="primary">
  <li>
    <ul class="secondary">
      <li><a href="">hover me makes ":after" change border color</a> </li>
      <li><a href="">text</a></li>
      <li><a href="">text</a></li>
      <li><a href="">text</a></li>
      <li><a href="">text</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help will use this method, after i edited it for you

Comment: shot man, just maybe edit your copy above aswell, forsome one else it would be confusing looking at the copy and then the snippet

Comment: Happy to Help ;-)